# How do I convert this tag-qualified selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For a new project I've been tasked with extracting all inline CSS to its own file.  Though I've figured out a good number of these HTML/CSS shenanigans this one has me puzzled:

```
<table class="border">
  <tr>
    <td>Logical</td>
    <td>Arbitrary</td>
    <td class="param_indent">Name of Ghostbuster. One of the following:<br>
      VENKMAN<br>
      STANTZ<br>
      SPENGLER<br>
      ZEDDEMORE
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Every** other entry is using the format "<.class> ", however the only way I can get this to work is as follows:

```
  td.param_indent {
    text-indent:-28px;
    padding-left:30px;  
 }
```

Without changing the rest of the cells in the row, can I format this [more efficiently?](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/)

Following is the entry for ".border":

```
.border table, .border td, .border tr, .border th {
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

Comment: Probably a specificity issue. Do you have any other rules potentially matching this td?

Comment: It is the child of a ".border" table, but changing that entry in the slightest causes all borders to disappear.  I'll edit the entry to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with a specificity issue, it's basically impossible to write a selector that will *work* without compromising on theoretical performance here. `.param_indent` is less specific than `.border td` and so declarations under that selector won't take precedence.

Other possible selectors that would resolve the specificity issue include `.border .param_indent`, but since descendant selectors are notorious for being the "worst" in terms of performance, and considering the `.border` entry *itself* consists of descendant selectors anyway, you're not really going to be able to wring any more efficiency out of this particular portion of your CSS.

So all I can say here is just stick with `td.param_indent`. If the descendant selector point is to be taken seriously, then `td.param_indent` is arguably better than something like `.border .param_indent`, for certain definitions of "better" anyway, even with the type selector.

Besides, unless you take the time to profile page renders yourself, you'll never know for sure if it's better, or if it's actually going to be *worse*.